# AJAX wrong encoding

Tags: ajax, encoding, utf-8

I'm having an issue with the wrong encoding being sent through AJAX.

My code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server_save.php",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: { data: <?php echo $data; ?> }

            }).done(function( msg ) {

            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });

    });
```

On my server, I've included this to ensure my encoding is UTF-8:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If I echo back the data via alert in my AJAX function, it looks fine:

```
'1120513','【接案】iOS遊戲 APP 程式設計','台中市全部', '', '','1.需要請提案人開發iOS系統上的電玩遊戲 app
2.各類型的遊戲都有需求,像是捲軸式的,或是動作類,休閒類的都有需求
3.需熟悉iOS系統SDK
4.需熟悉 C++/Objective-C 
5.請有經驗者提供過去作品供發案方參考','02','20130611', '','1','依公司規定','1','18','-1','104外包網'
```

But in my chrome developer tools (and when I save it into the database), the preview window [network->post->preview] shows:

```
1120513','ã€æŽ¥æ¡ˆã€‘iOSéŠæˆ² APP ç¨‹å¼è¨­è¨ˆ','å°ä¸­å¸‚å…¨éƒ¨', '', '','1.éœ
€è¦è«‹ææ¡ˆäººé–‹ç™¼iOSç³»çµ±ä¸Šçš„é›»çŽ©éŠæˆ² app2.å„é¡žåž‹çš„éŠæˆ²éƒ½æœ‰éœ€æ±‚,åƒæ˜¯æ²è»¸å¼çš„,æˆ–
æ˜¯å‹•ä½œé¡ž,ä¼‘é–’é¡žçš„éƒ½æœ‰éœ€æ±‚3.éœ€ç†Ÿæ‚‰iOSç³»çµ±SDK4.éœ€ç†Ÿæ‚‰ C++/Objective-C 5.è«‹æœ‰ç¶“é©—è
€…æä¾›éŽåŽ»ä½œå“ä¾›ç™¼æ¡ˆæ–¹åƒè€ƒ','02','20130611','1',''ä¾å…¬å¸è¦å®š','1','18','104å¤–åŒ…ç¶²
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Comment: it's not a problem with the database, as all the encoding is set to UTF-8, and manual queries with Chinese work fine

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an encoding error with PHP/MySQL. I did the below to fix it:

```
if( function_exists('mysql_set_charset') ){
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db_con);
}else{
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db_con);
}
```